# npm run build fails "only when" executed using Jenkins execute shell

Tags: jenkins, npm, shellexecute, npm-run, npm-build

Below is the `npm run build` when ran using `root` user from the command prompt on a Ubuntu Linux host:

As you can see from the output despite suggestions the command ran successfully as evident from the output of `echo $?`

[image]

However, when I run the same command using Jenkins "execute shell" with root user it fails as seen in the below output:

```
cd /etc/jenkins_tmp/workspace/SGGS_QA_UI;
npm run build
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "npm build was successful. Copying ...";
    else
    echo " npm install failed. Check Jenkins console out";
    fi
```

[image]

Output:

```
  Line 151:8:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'callSetLoggedIn', 'navigate', and 'setCurrentPage'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

src/pages/resetpassword/Resetpassword.jsx
  Line 1:29:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
  Line 14:8:  'ResendOtp' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars


Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as a failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have checked the resources, server health and disk space for Jenkins as well as the target server where the `npm run build` executes and everything looks fine.

Can you please suggest how can I identify and fix the issue so Jenkins can do a successful `npm run build`?

Comment: Any inputs Dear Users?

Comment: `CI=false npm run build` made it to work with Jenkins too. However, I don't know why was it not failing when executed using putty shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed to `CI=false npm run build` to resolve the issue as else it was considering the warning messages as error messages.

I still have no clue why it was not failing when running through the command line without Jenkins.